# Failed to start named.service : Unit not found?

Tags: linux, services, bind

I want to start named service on the second oracle LINUX version 7.9 server but I got this error

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart named.service
Failed to restart named.service: Unit not found.
```

I checked the path /var/named folder named not exist I created the folder

I tried to install the bind package but i got error :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-2 etc]# sudo dnf install bind
sudo: dnf: command not found
```

how to start named.service ?

Is there any package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the command :

```
# yum install bind
```

Then run the command to restart the named service

```
  # service named restart
```

DNF package started with Oracle Linux 8 or later.

Comment: thanks this solved it :)